# renaming the [Content Type] column

Tags: 2013, content-type, column, rename

My Custom List is based on Content Types. While modifying the view I get the option to display a column name called [Content Type], but I don't know how to rename it to something meaningful. That column does not appear anywhere on the SP designer so that I can rename it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but if it can be useful to others:

To change the name of a list / library columns ([Content Type], [ID] ...):

1. View Format: Quick Edit
2. Rename Column (Content Type exemple)

[image]

3. Stop editing this list

**No change, however, in EditForm.aspx**

[image]

Comment: Worked great for me!  I am using modern lists/libraries which may have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using powershell as the following:

```
$siteUrl = "http://YourServerName/sites/testsite" 
[system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Sharepoint") > $null 

#get the SPSite
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)

#Get the root web
$RootWeb = $site.RootWeb

#Find the list in the root web
$mylistname ="TheNameOfTheList"   
$myList= $RootWeb.Lists[$mylistname]

if ($myList -ne $null)
{
    $myContentType = $myList.ContentTypes["ExampleCT"]

    if ($myContentType -ne $null)
    {
        $myContentType.Name = "Example CT"
        $myContentType.Update()
    }

}
```

Original post:
[How to rename a Content Type associated to a List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54644/how-to-rename-a-content-type-associated-to-a-list)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but please note that I don't need to rename Content Type itself, but the list column named [Content Type]. This column is available when modifying list views, but is not available elsewhere on the list settings page.